# Exception handling for inherited classes

Tags: .net, exception

I currently have the situation where a class I am inheriting throws an exception under certain circumstances. Is there a simple way of "catching" an exception when it is thrown by the "Inherits" command?

Comment: "Inherits" isn't a command. It's part of a declaration. It's really not clear what you mean, or where you want the exception to be caught. Please provide a short but complete example of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand what is asked here.

Exceptions are thrown and caught when code is executing. You probably want to define a "catch" clause in your subclass which would catch all exceptions from your superclass, but that is a false approach. You always use pretty usual try-catch blocks to catch exceptions, and you must write it in the code which uses (calls) those original methods where an exception may be thrown, not in the subclass. This is because program must need to know where to continue after the catch block is executed.

If you just want to "do something and continue", you can use rethrow command (**throw;** in C#).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is put it in a try...catch block. I don't see what problem do you face.

```
Class SomeExistingClass
    Sub SomeMethodThatThrowsException()
        Throw New Exception("Demo exception!")
    End Sub
End Class

Class NewInheritedClass
    Inherits SomeExistingClass

    Sub SomeMethod()
        Try
            MyBase.SomeMethodThatThrowsException()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) ' or whatever
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```